# Block-Placement in a Feature via Context

Tags: 7, features, theming, distributions

I have got a Feature consisting of a few [boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes) and a context which puts those boxes in the right regions. That works if I install drupal and my theme and activate the feature.

But it does not work if i install it using drush site-install and my installation profile which contains my theme and my feature. I guess this is because the theme gets activated after the feature and so the feature does not know the regions while activating. What would you recommend to solve this? I could remove my feature as a dependency and activate it manually after my theme in myprofile.install, but is there a "cleaner" approach?

Answer (score 1):

i think doing it in profile.install is clean enough :)
you only set the theme to default in there anyway, dont you ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean "blocks" rather then boxes... It that is the case, you need to also download and Features Extra: http://drupal.org/project/features_extra

Once that is available, enable fe_block. That will add a machine name to your blocks. Fill in the machine name, and once done with that, you will see those blocks "available" when creating/updating a feature.

Comment: No, I am actually talking about [boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes). It is an alternative to standard blocks with built-in features support. I guess you did not read my whole posting ;)